# My method returns NULL instead of returning a 2D array

Tags: java, android, methods, multidimensional-array

I defined my method as below and would like to return a 2D array but instead it returns a NULL . Can some one tell me whats wrong with this?

```
public String[][] parseInput150(String[] inputPercent150, String[][] input150Parsed ) {

    String inputPer150fromXML = getResources().getString(R.string.InputPercent150);

    inputPercent150 = inputPer150fromXML.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
    input150Parsed = new String[inputPercent150.length-1][];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputPercent150.length; i++) {
        input150Parsed[i-1] = inputPercent150[i].split(Pattern.quote(" "));
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < input150Parsed.length; i++){

            Log.e("TAG","Parsed Array value = " + Arrays.toString(input150Parsed[i]));

    }

    return input150Parsed;      
}
```

The method call is below:

> ```
> @Override
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
>        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
>     operationalSoldiers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.operationalSoldiers);
>     operationalSoldiers.setText("150");        
>     initialInput = setinitialInput(initialInput);
>     input150Parsed = parseInput150(inputPercent150, input150Parsed);                        
>     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
>     selectAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
>     deselectAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deselectAll);        
>     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
>     array =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.facilities);
>     strings1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));                
>     TopicSelectionListAdapter topicSelectionListAdapter = new TopicSelectionListAdapter(
>             second.this, R.layout.listrow, strings1);
>     listView.setAdapter(topicSelectionListAdapter);
>     listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
>     listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
>     for(int i=0;i<strings1.size();i++){
>         listView.setItemChecked(i, false);
>       }
>        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
>                 long arg3) {
>             CheckedTextView selectedItem = (CheckedTextView) view;
>             boolean isChecked = selectedItem.isChecked();
>            Log.e("TAG","item clicked position = " + position + " isChecked = " + isChecked);
>             for(int i=0; i< strings1.size(); i++){
>                 if(!isChecked){
>                     bArray[i]= 1;
>                 }
>                 else{
>                     bArray[i]= 0;
>                 }
>                     System.out.print(bArray[i]);
>             }Log.e("TAG","boolean Array value = " + bArray);
>           }
>     });
>     selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             for(int i=0;i<strings1.size();i++){
>                 listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
>                 bArray[i]= 1;
>             }
>             totalSoldiers = (int) (operationalSoldiers.getAlpha() + (operationalSoldiers.getAlpha() * 0.13));
>             for (int r=0; r < input150Parsed.length; r++ ){
>                 for(int c=0; c < input150Parsed[r].length; c++){                        
>                     calculatedParValues[r][c] = ((totalSoldiers * (Integer.valueOf(input150Parsed[r][c]))) * Integer.valueOf(initialInput[c]));
>                 }
>             }
>           for (int i = 0; i < calculatedParValues.length; i++){
>         Log.e("TAG","Parsed parameter value = " + Arrays.toString(calculatedParValues[i]));
>         }
>           }
>     });
> ```

Comment: i dont see where youre returning anything at all, is this the whole method? have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: @Ash: sorry I pasted it correctly now. Yes I did, when I try to access input150Parsed in a diiferent method it shows NULL.

Comment: @Ash : Please see the below code.. I am trying to use "input150Parsed" in a different method as shown in the edited code above

Comment: Did you check what is value in input150Parsed using debugger? Is it correct value?

Comment: @Shreya: input150Parsed  has all the correct values and also I am logging the values to check. It does have all the coorect values but when I check this 'input150Parsed = parseInput150(inputPercent150, input150Parsed)' after returning, it does have NULL values.

Comment: Was input150Parsed initialized to null before you passed it to a function?

Comment: @Shreya: I declared a string 2D array, did not initialize it.
**String[][] input150Parsed;**

Comment: Ok.. Why are u passing it in a function? You can initialize a new string[][] there and return it

Comment: @Shreya: Can you find any mistake from the below for loop? The exception is being thrown here: 

***for (int r=0; r < input150Parsed.length; r++ ){
        for(int c=0; c < input150Parsed[r].length; c++){
                  
            calculatedParValues[r][c] = ((totalSoldiers *   (Integer.valueOf(input150Parsed[r][c]))) * Integer.valueOf(initialInput[c]));
                 }
                }***
                


It complains ""input150Parsed"  <error(s)_during_the_evaluation> "input150Parsed"  <error(s)_during_the_evaluation> ***input150Parsed cannot be resolved to a variable" ***

Comment: @Shreya:  I decalred float[][] calculatedParValues;

Comment: Is there any mistake in the above for loop? Can I address the array values as Integer.valueOf(input150Parsed[r][c])?